# Recursive Function Struct Simplify Fractions

Tags: c, function, recursion, fractions, simplify

I am having a hard here and could use some help (I have been at this for hours and am getting no where...). 
OK, so my problem is that I can't figure out how to make a Function that uses a typedef to return a simplified fraction. In other words I want to use Euclidean method to get GCD like this:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int rem;

    if ((rem = a % b) == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return gcd(b, rem);
    }
}
```

Then simply with something like this:

```
int result = gcd(num, den);
int simple_num = num / result;
int simple_den = den / result;
printf("%d / %d", simple_num, simple_den);
```

But, I am trying to make it with a typedef called fraction and use one function that will return my simplified numerator and denominator.

```
typedef struct
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
} Fraction;

Fraction simplify(Fraction myFraction)
{
    return myFraction;
}
```

Anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: You could implement `mod`, `div` and `equals` for your `Fraction` type and use `gcd`?

Comment: Yeah I thought something like that but I am trying to do it all with one function and not use gcd... but rather some other method like it. So far I have not been able to write something the works with the accuracy of gdc with out a recursive function

Comment: GCD can be implemented with a simple loop.  After computing `rem = a % b;`, set `a = b;` and `b = rem;`, and keep looping until `rem == 0`.

Comment: you may have to swap a and b if b is larger than a, right... it least that is what my saturday brain says

Comment: @Grady No need to swap since `a % b` is equal to `a` if `a` is less than `b`. So the swap (on the first pass through the loop) happens automatically `rem=a; a=b; b=rem;` The code _should_ check for `a==0 || b==0` before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Fraction simplify(Fraction myFraction)
{
   int result = gcd(myFraction.numerator, myFraction.denominator);
   int simple_num = num / result;
   int simple_den = den / result;
   Fraction newFraction = {simple_num, simple_den};
   return newFraction;
}
```